Constructing such a $0<\delta<1$ that $|z + w|\leq \delta |z|+|w|$ when $0<\varepsilon\leq |\mathrm{Arg}(z)-\mathrm{Arg}(w)|\leq 2\pi -\varepsilon$
Let $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$ be two non-zero complex numbers such that for some $\varepsilon > 0$ we have $$0<\varepsilon\leq |\mathrm{Arg}(z)-\mathrm{Arg}(w)|\leq 2\pi -\varepsilon$$
I am trying to construct a $1 > \delta(\varepsilon) := \delta > 0$ such that
$$|z + w|\leq \delta|z| + |w|$$
that is, an improved bound on the triangle inequality. Right now I don't know how to construct such a $\delta$ explicitly. One way to prove the existence of such a $\delta$ is to note that $|z + w| = |z| + |w|$ precisely when $z$ and $w$ are collinear. By assumption this is not the case, so $|z + w| < |z| + |w|$. Hence, there exists some $1 > \delta > 0$ such that
$$|z + w| = \delta (|z| + |w|)\leq \delta|z| + |w|$$
although I am not sure when equality is attained. As for the construction, if we first assume that $$0\leq \mathrm{Arg}(w) < \mathrm{Arg}(z)\leq \pi$$
then by writing $\gamma = \mathrm{Arg}(z)-\mathrm{Arg}(w)$ and using the cosine rule and the polarization identity we get
$$|z + w|^2 = 2|z||w|\cos(\gamma) + |z|^2 + |w|^2$$
and I don't know how to proceed beyond this point. The RHS suggests to me that we want to use some multiply/divide trickery with $\cos(\gamma)$ if $\gamma \neq \pi/2 k, k\in\mathbb{Z}$.
